# How can I instantiate Ruby's RestClient?

Tags: ruby, rest, oauth, rest-client

I need to get 2 different 'clients' for testing purposes(user/agent e-wallet mobile apps):

- 1 for user client
- 1 for agent client

Both of these clients should be signed with ouath headers. 
`RestClient` provide `#before_execution_proc` for such purposes, but this won't work for 2 different sessions at once. I've tried solve it with this [pull request](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/pull/137), but this is ugly way for multi resource(as I should run this code with every new resource requested):

```
def resource(url)
  rest = RestClient::Resource.new(@base_url+ url)
  rest.add_before_execution_proc do |req, params|
    @access_token.sign! req, {"Cookie" => @cookies}
  end
  rest
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with preparing a hash `url_regexp ⇒ access_token` and generic `add_before_execution_proc`:

```
 @access_tokens = { /google/ => ..., /msoft/ => ... }
 RestClient.add_before_execution_proc do |req, params|
   token = @access_tokens.detect { |req_rex, token| req_rex =~ req }.last
   token.sign!(req) unless token.nil?
 end
```

Of course the check should be done carefully, probably depending on both request and params.

Comment: token is an array because of usage `|req_rex, token|` in block, so your code wont work out of box. And this wont work if both apps share same urls i.e. ./login is same for both clients